# How can I rebrand Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

I'm making a custom remaster of ubuntu and I want to change the name of the Software Center. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
dpkg -S `which software-center`
```

That's how you find out what package something is in and it shows me you want to hack into the `software-center` package.

I'd start by forking one of the branches available on [its Launchpad page](https://code.launchpad.net/software-center).

Answer (score -1):

The USC is just a bunch of Python scripts so you can edit it. Here's where it lives:

```
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/
```

You can edit these directly if you wish. It's somewhat faster than repackaging your own version.

Answer (score -2):

Find out what package the Ubuntu Software Center is in, and modify the package. Note: my answer is just as short as your question.